# Elastic search storage: How to get the list of field names under _source?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am very new to using Elastic search storage and looking for a clue to find  the list of all fields listed under_source. So far, I have come across the ways to find out the values for the different fields defined under _source but not the way to list out all the fields. For example: I have below document

```
   {
      "took": 1,
      "timed_out": false,
      "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "skipped": 0,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
       {
         "_index": "my_product",
         "_type": "_doc",
         "_id": "B2LcemUBCkYSNbJBl-G_",
         "_score": 1,
         "_source": {
             "email": "123@abc.com",
             "product_0": "iWLKHmUBCkYSNbJB3NZR",
             "product_price_0": "10",
             "link_0": ""
          }
       }
      ]
    }
  }
```

So, from the above example, I would like to get the fields names like email, product_0, product_price_0 and link_0 which are under _source. I have been retrieving the values by parsing the array returned from the ess api but what should be at the ? mark to get the field names $result['hits']['hits'][0]['_source'][?]

Note: I am using php to insert data into ESS and retrieve data from it.

Comment: In which language you're trying to parse the response?

Comment: I am trying to parse the response in php. Sorry not to mention it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you need [array_keys](https://secure.php.net/array_keys)

```
array_keys($result['hits']['hits'][0]['_source'])
```